# Internal server error cgi script on apache2

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, apache2, cgi

So I have a CGI script(i just took my python script and renamed it to .cgi) that basically does some web scraping and writes a few files based on what he scraped.
However every time I try to run it, I get a Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).

This is my apache.conf:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/html/animals

<Directory /var/www/html/animals>
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
</Directory>
```

This is how I call the script:

```
<script>
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../animals/GetAnimals.cgi",
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log("Sucess!");
    }
});
</script>
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.request import Request
import json, codecs
from string import Template
import glob, os
import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable() 

filelist = glob.glob('*.txt')
for file in filelist:
    os.remove(file)

#open the website, save the html and close the connection
web_request = Request('super secret url', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 
Safari/537.36'})
web_client = urlopen(web_request)
html_page = web_client.read().decode('UTF-8')
web_client.close()
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')

#do a bunch of stuff with beautifulsoup and string manipulation

for animal in animals:
    #write a file here

data = {}
data['Animals'] = final_json
with open('animals.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

And yes I have enabled cgi with sudo a2enmod cgi and restarted after.

Comment: Have you looked in the web server error log?

Comment: Why are you calling a POST url without any body content?

Comment: Showing us your _code_ would be a lot more helpful than showing us just the imports.

Comment: added the code @JohnGordon

Comment: You don't appear to be returning any headers such as content-type or status code.  Any web application has to at least do those things.

Comment: @JohnGordon however I dont want to do that, I just want my application to run on the server. Is there a simpler way to make my app run on a click of a button? (That doesn't involve any libraries)